# Arcanist land: Exception Branch "master" does not exist in remote "origin"

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

I have blocked on this issue for days, and tried a lot, googled a lot, but didn't get valuable info.

I have done all phabricator config. And there weren't issue for diffusion.
I can rum arc diff correctly, but when I do arc lan, this issue came out.

Also I can play git init --bare, and then git pull, push correctly.
the git version is 2.7.2.

and the log with --trace flag is blew:

```
~/phabricator_test/test $ arc land --trace
 ARGV  '/mnt/data/arcanist/bin/../scripts/arcanist.php' 'land' '--trace'
 LOAD  Loaded "phutil" from "/mnt/data/libphutil/src".
 LOAD  Loaded "arcanist" from "/mnt/data/arcanist/src".
Config: Reading user configuration file "/home/pi/.arcrc"...
Config: Did not find system configuration at "/etc/arcconfig".
Working Copy: Reading .arcconfig from "/home/pi/phabricator_test/test/.arcconfig".
Working Copy: Path "/home/pi/phabricator_test/test" is part of `git` working copy "/home/pi/phabricator_test/test".
Working Copy: Project root is at "/home/pi/phabricator_test/test".
Config: Did not find local configuration at "/home/pi/phabricator_test/test/.git/arc/config".
>>> [0] <conduit> user.whoami() <bytes = 117>
>>> [1] <http> http://k88l.zicp.net/api/user.whoami
<<< [1] <http> 504,781 us
<<< [0] <conduit> 507,275 us
>>> [2] <exec> $ git symbolic-ref --quiet HEAD
<<< [2] <exec> 21,192 us
>>> [3] <exec> $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name 'master'@{upstream}
<<< [3] <exec> 23,760 us
>>> [4] <exec> $ git --version
<<< [4] <exec> 18,554 us
>>> [5] <exec> $ git ls-remote --get-url 'origin'
<<< [5] <exec> 19,594 us
>>> [6] <conduit> repository.query() <bytes = 224>
>>> [7] <http> http://k88l.zicp.net/api/repository.query
<<< [7] <http> 473,501 us
<<< [6] <conduit> 475,099 us
>>> [8] <exec> $ git symbolic-ref --quiet HEAD
<<< [8] <exec> 19,479 us
Landing current branch 'master'.
>>> [9] <exec> $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name 'master'@{upstream}
<<< [9] <exec> 20,928 us
>>> [10] <exec> $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name 'master'@{upstream}
<<< [10] <exec> 23,005 us
>>> [11] <exec> $ git symbolic-ref --quiet HEAD
<<< [11] <exec> 19,532 us
>>> [12] <exec> $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name 'master'@{upstream}
<<< [12] <exec> 21,270 us
 TARGET  Landing onto "master", the default target under git.
>>> [13] <exec> $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name 'master'@{upstream}
<<< [13] <exec> 21,100 us
 REMOTE  Using remote "origin", the default remote under git.
>>> [14] <exec> $ git diff --no-ext-diff --no-textconv --raw 'HEAD' --
>>> [15] <exec> $ git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
<<< [14] <exec> 23,727 us
<<< [15] <exec> 21,645 us
>>> [16] <exec> $ git diff-files --name-only
<<< [16] <exec> 19,523 us
>>> [17] <exec> $ git rev-parse --verify 'origin/master'
<<< [17] <exec> 19,762 us

[2016-03-07 09:21:39] EXCEPTION: (Exception) Branch "master" does not exist in remote "origin". at [<arcanist>/src/land/ArcanistGitLandEngine.php:101]
arcanist(head=stable, ref.master=9e78d15fc0c7, ref.stable=1439aaa87183), phutil(head=stable, ref.master=ad3f475c8c13, ref.stable=76425eaa8125)
  #0 ArcanistGitLandEngine::verifySourceAndTargetExist() called at [<arcanist>/src/land/ArcanistGitLandEngine.php:13]
  #1 ArcanistGitLandEngine::execute() called at [<arcanist>/src/workflow/ArcanistLandWorkflow.php:296]
  #2 ArcanistLandWorkflow::run() called at [<arcanist>/scripts/arcanist.php:392]
```

Comment: If you do a `git branch -a` does it list a branch called "remotes/origin/master"?  The error message would indicate that it doesn't exist.

Comment: "warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository."  I get this when I clone the reop. And checked `git branch -a` get noting output.

Answer (score -1):

This question has a good answer: [Phabricator first time 'arc land' fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35743582/1396322)

Basically you need to create the master branch on your remote for this to work.

Comment: He's commenting on using the `arc land` command, not the `arc diff` command.

Comment: Updated per commadelimited's comment.